# How do you disconnect a Bluetooth device in a Windows driver so that Windows doesn't lose it's pairing?

Tags: windows, driver, device

I'm currently working on a Windows driver for Nintendo Wii remotes and I want the PC to be able to disconnect the device without removing it's pairing. I know this behavior exists since my mouse is capable of doing it. What I want it to do is, when looking in Devices and Printers, the device should show as grayed out when off/out of range. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to do this, either because I don't know what this exact behavior is called or because it's never clearly stated in the documentation. Does anyone have any idea how this is implemented?

EDIT: Realized this was probably not a Bluetooth specific feature since printers also make use of this and removed the Bluetooth tag.

Comment: Do you work in user-mode or in kernel mode?

Comment: I'm working in kernel mode.

Comment: What kind of your driver? Is it HID? Is it Bluetooth filter?

Comment: It's a lower filter driver for HID if I'm understanding the terminology right. Because the Wiimote doesn't conform perfectly to the Bluetooth HID specifications, it has to modify/reroute a lot of the communication with the remote.

Comment: Ok. I see now. In fact as it is Bluetooth HID then you are in correct way. However you should get device disconnect notification from BT HID driver and should not worry about unpairing. Th icon state actually should be managed by the system that processes WM_DEVICExxx messages (or CM_XXX notifications).